# Is C# File.Copy close to the same thing as copying a file via explorer in terms of performance?

Tags: c#, system.io.file

We have a couple of office connected via MPLS lines.  We are supposed to get 10Mb/Second.  I do not mind being off by 1 or 2 Mbps in my testing.  I want to test from various work stations to see if all parts of the network are about the same or if there are some areas that have bottle necks.  I was asked to do drag and drop files over the network via Windows Explorer and time it to see what kind of speeds we are getting.  Does File.Copy use something close enough to copying via explorer under the hood to get a fairly accurate measurement.  If so, this would be nice because I can have the various PCs on the network launch my app via the task scheduler and report back to me.

Thanks

Comment: `File.Copy` is mapped on the Windows copy API. It'd make little sense if Windows Explorer didn't also use it.

Comment: `File.Copy` uses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [in the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,168), the `File.Copy` method internally uses a native Win32 call, specifically [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) (from [here in the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,5aafb3e2ba59bd23)).

The performance should be more or less the same as Windows Explorer. There is just a little overhead, but that wouldn't do anything in the actual copying.

Comment: So you are 100% sure Windows Explorer uses CopyFile/CopyFileEx to do the job?

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Idk, I just ask :)

Comment: Of course, and I like that question. We can assume that since there is nothing else but Win32 to call from Windows.

Comment: Explorer uses `CopyFile2` on Windows 8+ -
 see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170526-00/?p=96235 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449404(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: No, Explorer does *not* use `CopyFile`. Classically, it calls `SHFileOperation`. On Vista, this switched to `IFileOperation`, a COM interface. There is a wrapper for that built into .NET, but it's in the Visual Basic namespace: `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory`. Perfectly usable from C#, if you'd like. But probably not important; the performance will certainly be comparable between the two methods.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills. I can hardly imagine that has a major impact, but good to know.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54bef96f-3ca1-4dd7-a621-da2fa8d8b35b/windows-copyfile-function-bug?forum=vcgeneral claims CopyFile2 may have some benefits in LAN scenarios, but I haven't verified that.